# How to link 2 MySQL Databases with bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to insert rows from a specific table in a database to another database with a bash script. The two databases are on different servers. How can I do that?

I want something like this:

INSERT INTO db1.table1(row1, row2) SELECT row1,row2 FROM db2.table2;

But the databases are on different servers.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems you could benefit from inbuilt functionality called "Replication".

Comment: [mysql replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) also [percona toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit) has useful replication monitoring things in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `ssh` to execute a remote command and `mysldump` to get the rows from the remote db and mysql to insert the row to the local db.

`ssh <remoteuser>@<remoteServer> mysqldump -t -u <remoteDbUser> -p<remoteDbPass> <remoteDbName> <remoteDbTable> -w<whereCondition> | mysql -u <localDbUser> -p<localDbPass> <localDbName>`

Pay attenction that:

1. there is no space between -p and the password.
2. The -t option avoid the CREATE TABLE sql instruction

Use the man page for more information about the mysqldump command.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the [pt-archiver](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/pt-archiver.html) tool in Percona Toolkit.  It can copy or move rows from one instance to another.  It does its work efficiently and incrementally.

Example:

```
$ pt-archiver --no-delete \
    --source h=host1,D=db1,t=table1 \
    --dest h=host2,D=db2,t=table2 \
    --columns col1,col2 \
    --where "1=1" --limit 1000 --commit-each
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the operation between two MySQL databases on the same server, it is easy. See this thread:

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?61,3063,4004#msg-4004

If you want to transfer the data from a database on a different server, or if it is a different kind of database, it is more difficult and you'll probably have to use software or build some. MySQL doesn't have the database link feature that Oracle has

Answer (score 0):

see this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-create-connection.html
it's like mysql's db link.

Comment: Yeah, but virtually no one uses federated in MySQL.  It has too many bugs.